# What's the code in shapepar manual?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig, cutwin

In this manual, How the author did this wrapping by use `\cutout` and `\shapepar`.
would one write a code? please.
http://ctan.mirror.ftn.uns.ac.rs/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf
[image]

Comment: what is your question? The tex source for the document is in the same directory that you link to.

Comment: Read shapepar.pdf from the beginning, and understand the points as you go. Then read shapepar.ltx.

Comment: +1 vote to close the question @DavidCarlisle

Comment: you don't need to vote: as it is your question you can simply delete it if you wish.